# Not available memory unit

Tags: arrays, c, string, gdb

The idea is to restock certain product by getting stdin from user and compare it to string value of the array - for the product names

My function code

```c
void free_restock(){
    print_inventory();

    printf("What do u want to restock: ");
    char *temp_string_for_name;
    scanf("%s", &temp_string_for_name);
    
    printf("How much do u want to restock: ");
    int temp_val_for_restock = 0;
    scanf("%d", &temp_val_for_restock);

    for(int i = 0; (strlen(INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i])) != 0; i++){
        if(strcmp(temp_string_for_name, INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i]) == 0){
            INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i] += temp_val_for_restock;
            printf("Now u have %d from %s\n", INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[i], INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i]);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d", i);
    }

}
```

Arrays initialization

```c
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS 100
static int INVENTORY_AMOUNT_ARRAY[MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS];
static char INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS][MAX_SIZE_OF_ARRAYS];
```

My gdb error:

```c
0x00007ffff7e01ecb in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: This     char *temp_string_for_name;
    scanf("%s", &temp_string_for_name); does not make a sense. Instead of using an array you are using an uninitialized pointer that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: oh - i m so dumb thx

Comment: This for loop for(int i = 0; (strlen(INVENTORY_NAMES_ARRAY[i])) != 0; i++){ also does not make a sense You need to traverse the two-dimensional array and compare its elements with the entered string.